# How to convert 2 independent lists into single list

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have 2 lists as following, need to derive something similar as mentioned in output list . I tried to use java stream() on list B, for each value of list A. But it always returning me following error 
`no instance of type variable r exists so that conforms to r`.Appreciate all the helps

List A = `[{1}]`

List B = `[{4,5,6}]`

Output List, List C = `[{1,4} , {1,5} , {1,6}]`

Comment: If you can add your code, is more easy to aid in your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a custom object to keep the values from two different lists.

```
public class ResultObj {
    private Integer valueA;
    private Integer valueB;
    public ResultObj(Integer valueA, Integer valueB) {
        this.valueA = valueA;
        this.valueB = valueB;
    }
    // getters, setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + valueA + "," + valueB + "}";
    }

}
```

Try this:

```
List<ResultObj> output = listA.stream().flatMap(a -> listB.stream().map(b -> new ResultObj(a, b)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(output);
```

Output:

```
[{1,4}, {1,5}, {1,6}]
```

Comment: can simplify `.map(a -> listB.stream().map(b -> new ResultObj(a, b))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())).flatMap(List::stream)` to `.flatMap(a -> listB.stream().map(b -> new ResultObj(a, b)))`

Comment: Thank you! it did solved my problem. Worked like a charm

Comment: Hi @SUKUMARS glad it helped, would you consider accepting/upvoting the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help:

```java
List<Integer> listA = Arrays.asList(1);
List<Integer> listB = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6);

List<List<Integer>> result = listA.stream().flatMap(a -> listB.stream().map(b -> Arrays.asList(a, b)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(result);
```

Result:

```
[[1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6]]
```